# Is it sufficient to have $\limsup \left\vert \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} \right\vert > 1$ in the quotient-criterion for infinite sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The quotient-criterion for infinite sequences tells us that a sequence $\sum a_n$ diverges, if $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\vert \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} \right\vert > 1$. But what if I write $\limsup$ instead of $\liminf$? Does anyone know a counterexample for $\limsup$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let Let $a_n=\frac1{2^n}$ unless $n$ is a power of $2$, in which case let $a_n=\frac1{2^{n-2}}$. Then

$$\frac{a_{2^n}}{a_{2^n-1}}=\frac{2^{2^n-1}}{2^{2^n-2}}=2\;,$$

so $\limsup_na_n=2$, but

$$\sum_na_n=\sum_n\frac1{2^n}+\sum_n\left(\frac1{2^{2^n-2}}-\frac1{2^{2^n}}\right)=2+3\sum_n\frac1{2^{2^n}}<\infty\;.$$